# How can I sum an array with D3?

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I'm struggling with summing an array. I don't have any error so I am not sure how to make it work.

my data passed to the function look like this:

```
{Region:'' ,freq:{yesVote:0, noVote:0}}
```

I try to sum it like this:

```
    // compute pie slice angles
    var pie = d3.pie().sort(null).value(function (d) {
        var yesTotal;
        var noTotal;
        console.log(d);

        yesTotal = d3.sum(d, function(v){
            console.log(v.freq);
           return v.freq.yesVote;
        });

        noTotal = d3.sum(d, function(v){
           return v.freq.noVote;
        });

        console.log(yesTotal);
        console.log(noTotal);

        return [yesTotal,noTotal];
    });
```

Sum function returns 0 and log function inside sum functions doesn't appear in the console (first log print data properly) so I assume there is something wrong with data passed to the sum function. Can you please explain me where I do mistake?

EDIT

printed data:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is what `console.log(d)` is producing:

```
{Region:'' ,freq:{yesVote:0, noVote:0}}
```

then yes, you're not passing the correct data. You're only passing an object with a single value set. `d3.sum()` should operate on the full array of data. Example:

```
var data = [
  {Region: 'A' ,freq: {yesVote:1, noVote:10}},
  {Region: 'B' ,freq: {yesVote:2, noVote:11}},
  {Region: 'C' ,freq: {yesVote:3, noVote:12}}
];

yesTotal = d3.sum(data, function(d) {
  return d.freq.yesVote;
});

noTotal = d3.sum(data, function(d) {
  return d.freq.noVote;
});

console.log(yesTotal)
6
console.log(noTotal)
33
```

Try moving the sum out of the pie chart value function, because inside, `d` is just a single row from your entire data set.

Comment: I am sorry I wrote unclearly. Data is passed correctly so even if there is only one value it should return it instead of 0 right? Thanks for the suggestion I will think how to use it outside of the function.

Comment: What's the result of `console.log(d)` in your code? It looks to from the screenshot it's a single JavaScript object like: `{Region: 'North Region', freq: {yesVote: 212951, noVote: 546138}}`

Comment: I have added a picture of all results to the EDIT

Comment: Cool, so in my example, if I did `console.log(data)` (equivalent to your `console.log(d)`) I would see the _whole_ array containing all data regions. The reason you're seeing all the records in the console is `d3.pie().sort(null).value(function (d) {})` is **looping through your array** type data set. If d was correct for the sum functions, you would see it print the whole array of all data points over and over again for every console output, though you'd be incorrectly calculating the sum over and over again. Try passing the sum function your original data var as it was passed to d3.pie.

Comment: Thank you for help. Now I sum all relevant data before pie function and pass an array with yes/no votes instead of all data. It works fine :) Thanks again.

Comment: Glad it worked! With D3 it's always good to consider whether you're operating on your entire data set or a single row. Unfortunately, JavaScript and D3 are flexible enough that it's easy to misuse an object vs array and not see any errors.